# Hyper-V Networking Does Not work on corporate network

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I'll try to explain without confusing you.

I built multiple Hyper-V VM's (using External VS, not Internal VS) on Windows 10 and when I'm connected to my home network, all is well. I can get out to the internet. Everything works as expected.

When I connect to my corporate network via Eth, strange things happen.

- Linux VM does not get an IP
- Win10 Network Adapters show VS with a public IP - 146... (strange)
- Laptop stops routing via corp network and instead is routing using the VS IP (also strange)

As I said, none of these problems occur at home so if there's a specific IT policy blocking me at work, I would appreciate knowing which one so I can tell my Help Desk what to fix. Or is it something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do a `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` (Windows) or a `sudo dhclient -v -r` and `sudo dhclient -v` (Linux) on the remote machine to get it to renew its DHCP settings and retrieve an IP address.

Comment: Thanks. On the Win side doing the release/renew worked and I get a private IP on Eth0. The external VS still has the public IP (146...). sudo dhclient -v/-r had no effect on the VM. It did not get an IP because, I assume, the VS still has that public IP.

Comment: Our IT team told me the 146... IP I'm getting is correct, so that part is resolved. Now to resolve this goofy VM IP problem.